# Double Unpivot?

Tags: sql-server, unpivot

I'm needing to unpivot the below table so that the output looks as shown in below image.

[image]

Does this require me to perform an UNPIVOT twice on the dataset or can I accomplish my expected output by using UNPIVOT once and specifying all the available Month and Value columns?

Should my script look something like the following to accomplish what I need?

```
 Select ID, Name, Age, Gender,Month,Value
    FROM
    (Select ID, Name, Age, Gender,Month1,Month2,Month3,Month4,Value1,Value2,Value3,Value4
    FROM MyTable
    ) as cp
    UNPIVOT 
    (
      Month FOR Months IN (Month1, Month2, Month3,Month4),
      Value for Values IN (Value1,Value2,Value3,Value4)
    ) AS up;
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

What you want to do is a [cross apply instead of an unpivot](https://www.sqlserverscience.com/t-sql/cross-apply-as-an-alternative-to-unpivot/).  That allows multiple columns to be unpivoted whereas `UNPIVOT` only allows a single column to be unpivoted.

Something like this:

```
CREATE TABLE dbo.Struc
(
    ID int NOT NULL
    , Person nvarchar(30) NOT NULL
    , Age int NOT NULL
    , Gender char(1) NOT NULL
    , Month1 int NOT NULL
    , Value1 int NOT NULL
    , Month2 int NOT NULL
    , Value2 int NOT NULL
);

INSERT INTO dbo.Struc (ID, Person, Age, Gender, Month1, Value1, Month2, Value2)
VALUES (1, 'Jane', 20, 'F', 201507, 1, 201508, 0)
    , (2, 'John', 30, 'M', 201507, 0, 201508, 1);

SELECT s.ID
    , s.Person
    , s.Age
    , s.Gender
    , v.Month
    , v.Value
FROM dbo.Struc s
CROSS APPLY (VALUES 
                  (Month1, Value1)
                , (Month2, Value2)
            ) v(Month, Value);
```

The results:

```
+----+--------+-----+--------+--------+-------+
| ID | Person | Age | Gender | Month  | Value |
+----+--------+-----+--------+--------+-------+
|  1 | Jane   |  20 | F      | 201507 |     1 |
|  1 | Jane   |  20 | F      | 201508 |     0 |
|  2 | John   |  30 | M      | 201507 |     0 |
|  2 | John   |  30 | M      | 201508 |     1 |
+----+--------+-----+--------+--------+-------+
```